# tezos node and tezos-client 8.2 running in docker I get "Illegal instruction (core dumped)"

Tags: node, docker

When running Tezos 8.2 docker images on my older CPU the node doesn't start.

I get an `Illegal instruction (core dumped)` error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that the CPU you are trying to run Tezos on does not support the encryption instructions that most modern CPUs do support these days.

You can rebuild Tezos from scratch, which will build the binaries without using these instructions, but your CPU is likely pretty slow already.

Solutions:

- Get a modern CPU and continue using the standard docker images
- Build Tezos from sources which will give you binaries suitable for your computers CPU. Could take a long time!

Answer (score 2):

To generate docker images from scratch locally, the full recipe is (a lot of patience and disk space)

```
$ wget https://gitlab.com/tezos/opam-repository/-/archive/v8.2/opam-repository-v8.2.tar.bz2
$ tar xf opam-repository-v8.2.tar.bz2
$ cd opam-repository-v8.2/
$ scripts/create_docker_image.sh tezos_build_deps v8.2
$ cd ..
$ wget https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/archive/v8.2/tezos-v8.2.tar.bz2
$ tar xf tezos-v8.2.tar.bz2
$ cd tezos-v8.2/
$ scripts/create_docker_image.sh tezos v8.2 tezos_build_deps v8.2 xxxx
```

Pick your favorite in between `tezos:v8.2`, `tezos-bare:v8.2` and `tezos-debug:v8.2` (and maybe remove the `build_tezos*` to save space...)